# Order by the difference of two selects in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table like this:

```
groupX    groupY    quantity
A         B         10
A         C         2
C         D         7
B         A         13
C         B         1
D         B         9
```

So, the same individuals appear at columns groupX and groupY. I would like to write a Select that makes the following:

```
Select 
  (Select groupX, sum(quantity) group by groupX) as M 
  - (Select groupY, sum(quantity) 
group by groupY) as N 
ORDER BY M-N Desc
```

I mean, I need to sum the quantities for each individual when they appear at groupX and when they appear at groupY and then calculate the difference for each individual between first and second quantity. Finally I need the query to order the individuals by that difference.

Of course the query I wrote does not work.

Comment: i corrected my code, please coment if you encounter an error

Comment: yes, I found an error, but basically the answer was great, so it's ok for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With this table as source

```
CREATE TABLE tableA
    (`groupX` varchar(1), `groupY` varchar(1), `quantity` int)
;

INSERT INTO tableA
    (`groupX`, `groupY`, `quantity`)
VALUES
    ('A', 'B', 10),
    ('A', 'C', 2),
    ('C', 'D', 7),
    ('B', 'A', 13),
    ('C', 'B', 1),
    ('D', 'B', 9)
;
```

You get with this statement

```
SELECT T1.groupX groupname, (sum1 - sum2)  as res
From 
  (SELECT groupX ,Sum(quantity) sum1 From tableA Group by groupX) T1
  inner join (SELECT groupY,Sum(quantity) sum2 From tableA Group by groupY) T2
  On T1.groupX = T2.groupY
  ORDER by res;
```

You will get

```
groupname  res
B          -7
A          -1
D          2
C          6
```

As i don't know all your data, it can be that it is better ti use Left join, which would include all unique memebers of groupX that have no corresponding group in groupY.
With right join it is vice versa

See example here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6c2facaaf6564d4025f24f6aab35adf7